# Recording live audio stream on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, audio, software-rec, streaming

What is a handy way to record live audio stream (mp3) from terminal, using command line?

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Comment: Why not `arecord`?

Comment: @Philippos `arecord`: does it support mp3? Live stream is mp3 format. From what I see from man, `arecord` only  use voc, wav, raw or au  file types.

Comment: I didn‘t read you want mp3. It needs more cpu resources to compress your recording.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of parec and ffmpeg/mpg123/lame, e.g.

```
parec --monitor-stream="$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | awk '$1 == "index:" {print $2}')" | ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 -i pipe: out.mp3
```

This will work **only** if you have a **single** application outputting audio.

Comment: I just want save original audio stream, without re-encoding. Can I use for this more simple commands `ffmpeg -i "http://media/stream/url:8024" out.mp3` or `wget -O File-name.mp3 "http://media/stream/url:8024"`?

Comment: If the source stream is already in mp3, wget might work just fine.

The above command was given in case you don't have direct access to the audio being played.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use wget like

```
wget http://ice1.somafm.com/dronezone-256-mp3
```

This will reply with

```
--2024-02-03 10:47:20--  http://ice1.somafm.com/dronezone-256-mp3
Resolving ice1.somafm.com (ice1.somafm.com)... 173.239.76.148
Connecting to ice1.somafm.com (ice1.somafm.com)|173.239.76.148|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [audio/mpeg]
Saving to: ‘dronezone-256-mp3’
```

Answer (score -1):

Use streamripper:

```bash
apt-get install streamripper
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _how_ to apply this tool to solve the problem (i.e. record a live audio stream).